# ¿Qué significa "sacalepuntas" en México?

Tags: definiciones, méxico

He oido esta expresión en México. Por ejemplo:

> Jorge anda muy sacalepuntas.

¿Cuál es su signficado? ¿Por qué?

Comment: Soy del sur de México y se usa como sinónimo de valiente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sácalepuntas es un coloquialismo utilizado en dos formas:

1. Cuando te refieres a que una persona anda un poco malhumorado, generalmente cualquier cosa le molesta, está irritado, y eso crea que lo que responda sea un poco rudo, por ejemplo:
   Mi jefe llegó el día de hoy muy sácalepuntas.
2. Caso contrario es cuando lo utilizan para nombrar a alguien que está feliz y posiblemente "presumiendo" un objeto material que acaba de adquirir, por ejemplo:
   Mi compañero de trabajo anda muy sácalepunta con su auto nuevo.

Para distinguir es necesario el contexto de donde se usa la palabra, pero básicamente son esos dos casos.

Solo para complementar, el por qué para ambos casos tiene que ver con afilar la punta de un lápiz:
Para el 1, el que está de malas, el lápiz queda muy filoso, puntiagudo, por lo que pudiera "picar" o lastimar a alguien, que es lo que está haciendo la persona.
En el caso 2, si está presumiendo, es porque está estrenando algo, lo cual hace referencia a limpio y nuevo, tal como un lápiz recién afilado.

Answer (score 4):

Esta expresión es exclusivamente usada en México y la he escuchado muchas veces pero no en los contextos que menciona @Gabriel. 
Sácalepunta tiene que ver, como bien se ha explicado, con un lápiz recien afilado con el sacapuntas; de dicho lápiz coloquialmente decimos que ha quedado "picudo". Alguien picudo es aquel listo, inteligente, sagaz, valiente, astuto o apto para algo específico, por lo tanto no es que presuma un objeto sino que hace derroche de sus dotes(rozando la prepotencia) ante alguna situación particular. Ejemplos:

ejemplo 1

> - Yo podría vencer boxeando a esos 2 hombres juntos.
> - apoco muy sacalepuntas?
> - por supuesto que si.

ejemplo 2

> - Este examen lo apruebo incluso sin estudiar.
> - apoco muy sacalepuntas?
> - lo que pasa es que esta clase es muy fácil para mi.

Answer (score 1):

en el norte se usa para referirse a alguien muy "picudo", afrentoso, insultante... Cuando a alguien se le dice "sácale punta" generalmente se le está menospreciando o subestimando porque se entiende que la persona alardea de más y al final le bajan los sumos... "andaba muy sácale-punta y lo corrieron a chingazos"